# 56 Received HTTP code 403 from proxy after CONNECT?

Tags: php, curl, salesforce, ssl-certificate, php-openssl

I am getting an "56 Received HTTP code 403 from proxy after CONNECT" Error while generating a lead to salesforce using cUrl from my web page. SSL certificate of the site is already expired.

UPDATED:

my code is as follows:

```
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $_url);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, count($field));
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query_data);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "cusom module");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add

```
AllowCONNECT port[-port] [port[-port]] ...
```

below `ProxyRequests On` in `httpd_proxy.conf` of apache proxy

eg:

```
ProxyRequests On
AllowCONNECT 443 563 5000
```

`5000` is port of destination address.

Comment: Where we should add the above-mentioned code?