# PHP cURL request fails on https call with errno 56: "Received HTTP code 403 from proxy after CONNECT"

Tags: php, curl

Server: Centos 8 (fully updated)
PHP Version: 7.4 (FPM)

I am trying to make a call with cURL (and also tried with Guzzle) and I am getting the same problem with only HTTPS URLs. HTTP urls are fine and no problems.

Here is some sample code:

```php
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_CAINFO => BASEPATH . "/data/cacert.pem",
    CURLOPT_URL => $url
));
```

The exact cURL error is: `Received HTTP code 403 from proxy after CONNECT`

The Apache virtual host is not using any proxy. I think this is somehow being stopped between Apache and PHP-FPM. The logs out put is not helpful. I have ruled out SELinux and mod_security as being the issue. Disabled both and still get the same result.

Another question mentions adding the following to `https_proxy.conf`

```
ProxyRequests On
AllowCONNECT 443 563 5000
```

But this has not yielded any results. The reason is because I am *not* using an http proxy in any http configurations.

Comment: did you review [**similar questions?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42572026/56-received-http-code-403-from-proxy-after-connect)

Comment: Yes, that is not applicable in my situation.

Comment: Why not? We don't know this, please update your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found out what the problem was. I had an unused environment variable in my `.env` file which was setting a proxy that I usually use on my dev machine. The script was failing on the production machine.

Turns out cURL and Guzzle automatically load those environment variables in with their requests, thus causing a proxy connection refusal. I removed the variable and everything works as expected.

Live and learn.